# Left navigation menu link wont stay highlighted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I keep the left nav menu named "Colors, Fonts, & Images highlighted when I click another link in the submenu?

In the first picture, when I "click colors, fonts, and images" on the left navigation panel, it remains highlighed.

[image]

Yet in the second image, when I click on the"Fonts" tab located in the middle, the "Colors, Fonts, & Images" tab on the left is no longer highlighted. How do I keep it highlighted?

[image]

code

```
/* eslint-disable no-shadow */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as S from './SideMenu.style';
import { setSidemenu } from '../../../redux/actions';
import SideMenuLink from './SideMenuLink';
import SideMenuSubLink from './SideMenuSubLink';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { isSidemenuOpen: state.isSidemenuOpen };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setSidemenu: (isSidemenuOpen) => dispatch(setSidemenu(isSidemenuOpen)),
  };
};

const links = [
  {
    text: 'Atoms',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/atoms',
  },
  {
    text: 'Molecules',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/molecules',
  },
  {
    text: 'Pages',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/pages',
  },
  {
    text: 'Containers & Controls',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/ui-palettes/containers-palettes',
  },
  {
    text: 'Colors, Fonts, & Images',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/ui-palettes/colors-palettes',
  },
  {
    text: 'Data Sources',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/data-sources',
  },
  {
    text: 'Deployments',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/deployments',
  },
  {
    text: 'Project Defaults',
    to: '/projects-main/projects/blank',
  },
];

const resetToggle = [false, false, false, false, false, false];

function ConnectedSideMenu({ setSidemenu, isSidemenuOpen }) {
  const [linkIndex, setLinkIndex] = useState(null);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState([...resetToggle]);
  return (
    <S.SideMenuWrapper isOpen={isSidemenuOpen}>
      <S.CollapseContainer isOpen={isSidemenuOpen}>
        <S.CollapseButton
          id="sideCollapseBtn"
          onClick={() => setSidemenu(!isSidemenuOpen)}
          isOpen={isSidemenuOpen}
        >
          {isSidemenuOpen ? (
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
          ) : (
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          )}
        </S.CollapseButton>
      </S.CollapseContainer>
      {links.map(({ text, to }, index) => (
        <S.LinkWrapper key={`menu-parent-${to}-${text}`}>
          <SideMenuLink
            activeStyle={
              text === 'UI Palettes' ? {} : { textDecoration: 'underline' }
            }
            to={to}
            onClick={() => {
              setLinkIndex(index);
              const copyToggle = [...resetToggle];
              copyToggle[index] = !toggle[index];
              setToggle(copyToggle);
            }}
          >
            {text}
          </SideMenuLink>
          {'links' in links[index] && linkIndex === index && toggle[index]
            ? // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
              links[index].links.map(({ text, to }) => (
                <SideMenuSubLink
                  activeStyle={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}
                  to={to}
                  key={`menu-child-${to}-${text}`}
                >
                  {text}
                </SideMenuSubLink>
              ))
            : null}
        </S.LinkWrapper>
      ))}
    </S.SideMenuWrapper>
  );
}

ConnectedSideMenu.propTypes = {
  setSidemenu: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isSidemenuOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const SideMenu = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(ConnectedSideMenu);

export default SideMenu;
```

Comment: Could you possibly share a codepen.io or codesandbox.io link where we can see your code in action and work with it to resolve this issue? I have a feeling this is a fairly simple request. I think it's just a matter of styling the active state vs. assigning a class while the associated label's content is shown.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell dang i wish i could but i dont think i can unfortunately because the project is a startup/private and is under production :(

Comment: feel free to send me a private link or email to reach out to you at where we can exchange private data related to this project. Happy to help and even sign an NDA. I just need to see the project to work with it.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell i dont think the owner would approve of it :(. would live sharing my screen on discord or something be worth it? or is that too much of a hassle?

Comment: FYI a request for a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a running codesandbox doesn't mean necessarily we need to see your proprietary code, but just a reasonable facsimile that reproduces the issue you face. What sort of link components are you rendering?

Comment: Trueeee ^^ @DrewReese

Comment: @jabinx92 screen sharing could still work but there's too much back and forth without actually being able to control the code. Could you set up a sandboxed example as Drew mentioned, but remove any of the proprietary info you don't want the public seeing?

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell let me see if i can whip something up in codesandbox :)